# Multi step jquery divs not displaying data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a multistep booking system where as the customer will fill out information in 4 steps on the header the steps are shown but the problem is there I wanted to give access to the users so if by mistakenly the user inputs incorrect information they have access to jump out that step and correct their information can anyone  help me out as of now when ever the step is clicked that step is shown but the thing is that the active div is not disappearing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.booking_step').on('click', function() {
        var step = $(this).attr('data-step');

        if(step == 1) {
            $('.schedule').fadeOut();
            $('.minfo').fadeOut();
            $('.select_rm').fadeIn(2500);
        }

        if(step == 2) {
            $('.select_rm').fadeOut();
            $('.minfo').fadeOut();
            $('.schedule').fadeIn(2500);
        }
    });
});

$(".step1").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.select_rm').fadeOut();
    $('.schedule').fadeIn(2500);
}));

$(".step2").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.schedule').fadeOut();
    $('.main_box').fadeIn(2500);
}));

$(".step3").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.minfo').fadeOut();
    $('.main_box').fadeIn(2500);
}));
```

```css
a {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.booking_step {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="steps">
  <div class="booking_step complete" data-step="1">
   <span class="bh_tittle">Clean Type</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="booking_step no_hd dt_schl" data-step="2">
   <span class="bh_tittle">Schedule Date</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="booking_step no_hd dt_ad_t" data-step="3">
   <span class="bh_tittle">Address</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="booking-flow-section select_rm" data-section="1" style="display: block;">
  <h1>Clean Type Form</h1>
  <a class="step1">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="booking-flow-section schedule" data-section="2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Schedule Date Form</h1>
  <a class="step2">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="booking-flow-section main_box" data-section="3" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Address Form</h1>
  <a class="step3">Next</a>
</div>
```

I am unable to recognize how come the div's will be hidden once which is currently active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to below code should work Please try. I think this what you have missed.

`$('.minfo').fadeOut();` is changed to `$('.main_box').fadeOut();`

```
  <style type="text/css">
    a {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.booking_step {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 20px
}
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="steps">
    <div class="booking_step complete" data-step="1">
      <span class="bh_tittle">Clean Type</span>
    </div>

    <div class="booking_step no_hd dt_schl" data-step="2">
      <span class="bh_tittle">Schedule Date</span>
    </div>

    <div class="booking_step no_hd dt_ad_t" data-step="3">
      <span class="bh_tittle">Address</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="booking-flow-section select_rm" data-section="1" style="display: block;">
  <h1>Clean Type Form</h1>
  <a class="step1">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="booking-flow-section schedule" data-section="2" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Schedule Date Form</h1>
  <a class="step2">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="booking-flow-section main_box" data-section="3" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Address Form</h1>
  <a class="step3">Next</a>
</div>                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.booking_step').on('click', function() {
        var step = $(this).attr('data-step');

        if(step == 1) {
            $('.schedule').fadeOut();
            $('.main_box').fadeOut();
            $('.select_rm').fadeIn(2500);
        }

        if(step == 2) {
            $('.select_rm').fadeOut();
            $('.main_box').fadeOut();
            $('.schedule').fadeIn(2500);
        }
    });
});

$(".step1").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.select_rm').fadeOut();
    $('.schedule').fadeIn(2500);
}));

$(".step2").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.schedule').fadeOut();
    $('.main_box').fadeIn(2500);
}));

$(".step3").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.minfo').fadeOut();
    $('.main_box').fadeIn(2500);
}));

                          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fadeOut()` use `hide()`.

`fadeOut()` has an animation on it.

---

Also for your jQuery, you could do a simple modification :

```js
$(".step1, .step2, .step3").on('click', (function(e) {
    $('.select_rm').hide();
    $('.schedule').fadeIn(2500);
}));
```

This way, you don't duplicate your code.

Comment: yes I would but don't you think this is not what I asked actually like if I I am on address for and then I click on clean type the clean type div is visible  but address form is not hidden then

Comment: but the problem is that all the 3 steps have different class don't you think it would work as of i tested but it is not wrking for me

Comment: There are a lot of plugins to do what you want. Check out : [jQuery Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/). The source code is available after the example. There are quite some issues with your code that needs to be fixed. I thought (when reading your question) that the problem was the overlapping between 2 tabs (when changing from one to the other). It looks like you were talking about the general structure.